# How to write mongo group by and sum aggregate functions in laravel eloquent raw method?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I wrote some code to fetch data within date range using laravel eloquent raw method. But I don't know how to write mongodb `groupby` and `sum` in laravel eloquent raw method. Please help me to take `sum(prepayment_amount)` and `sum(total_prepayment_amount)` group by `checkin_from` date. The expecting result is given below. Thanks

**DashbardController.php**

```
    $cabinName              = $request->cabin;
    $daterange              = explode("-", $request->daterange);
    $dateBegin              = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime($daterange[0])*1000);
    $dateEnd                = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime($daterange[1])*1000);
    $bookings               = Booking::raw(function ($collection) use ($cabinName, $dateBegin, $dateEnd) {
       return $collection->aggregate([
          [
            '$match' => [
                         'is_delete' => 0,
                         'cabinname' => $cabinName,
                         'checkin_from' => ['$gte' => $dateBegin, '$lte' => $dateEnd]
                         ],
          ],
       ]);
   });
   dd($bookings);
```

**Booking Collection**

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("58046a49f8f888a80b00002a"), "cabinname" : "Matras-Haus", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2016-09-17T00:00:00Z"), "prepayment_amount" : "20", "total_prepayment_amount" : "25", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2016-09-17T06:06:01Z"), "reservation_cancel" : "2", "is_delete" : NumberLong(1), "payment_status" : "1" }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("58183678d2ae67a404431d5c"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2016-10-31T23:00:00Z"), "prepayment_amount" : "30", "total_prepayment_amount" : "40", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2016-11-01T06:30:16Z"), "reservation_cancel" : "2", "is_delete" : NumberLong(1), "payment_status" : "0" }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("581b31f3d2ae674d5f431d5b"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2016-10-31T23:00:00Z"), "prepayment_amount" : "35", "total_prepayment_amount" : "45", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2016-11-03T12:47:47Z"), "reservation_cancel" : "2", "is_delete" : NumberLong(1) }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5821af65d2ae67c82154efc5"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2016-09-05T22:00:00Z"), "prepayment_amount" : "40", "total_prepayment_amount" : "45", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2016-11-08T10:56:37Z"), "reservation_cancel" : "2", "is_delete" : NumberLong(1) }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("582558d4d2ae679c4d8b4567"), "cabinname" : "Matras-Haus", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2016-09-17T22:00:00Z"), "prepayment_amount" : "20", "total_prepayment_amount" : "23", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2016-08-17T05:36:20Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(1) }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("58352c3cd2ae672341ec89e1"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2016-09-05T22:00:00Z"), "prepayment_amount" : "50", "total_prepayment_amount" : "55", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2016-08-05T05:42:20Z"), "reservation_cancel" : "2", "is_delete" : NumberLong(1) }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("58352c3cd2ae672341ec887e1"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-10-05T22:00:00Z"), "prepayment_amount" : "50", "total_prepayment_amount" : "55", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2017-08-05T05:42:20Z"), "reservation_cancel" : "2", "is_delete" : NumberLong(1) }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("58352c3cd2ae672341ec887e1"), "cabinname" : "Matras-Haus", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-10-05T22:00:00Z"), "prepayment_amount" : "50", "total_prepayment_amount" : "55", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2017-08-05T05:42:20Z"), "reservation_cancel" : "2", "is_delete" : NumberLong(1) }
```

**Expecting result**

```
prepayment_amount total_prepayment_amount    checkin_from  cabinname

40                       48                  2016-09-17    Matras-Haus

50                       55                  2017-10-05    Matras-Haus

65                       85                  2016-10-31    Kemptner Hütte

90                       110                 2016-09-05    Kemptner Hütte

50                       55                  2017-10-05    Kemptner Hütte
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your amount values to numeric from string and use below aggregation.

You can add `$group` to sum the amount values and `$project` to format the response.

```
[
   '$match' => 
      [
           'is_delete' => 0,    
           'cabinname' => $cabinName,
           'checkin_from' => ['$gte' => $dateBegin, '$lte' => $dateEnd]
      ],
],
[
   '$group' => 
      [
          '_id' => ['checkin_from' => '$checkin_from','cabinname' => '$cabinname'], 
          'total_prepayment_amount' => ['$sum' => '$total_prepayment_amount'], 
          'prepayment_amount' => ['$sum' => '$prepayment_amount'] 
      ],
],
[
   '$project' => 
      [
          'checkin_from' => '$_id.checkin_from',
          'cabinname' => '$_id.cabinname', 
          'total_prepayment_amount' => 1,
          'prepayment_amount' => 1 
      ],
],
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will update prepayment_amount and total_prepayment_amount to numeric and try your answer. Then I will update the status here.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have changed the type to double then it is working correctly.